# Java - Case insensitive split WITH VARIABLE splitting string

Tags: java, regex, split

[program test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wJLY.png)
so I have a program that will be given two strings as arguments: base and remove. It has to take out remove from base. I am using the split method to remove the second string from the first. However, the case on the chars of the second string should not matter, while the case of the first string must be preserved. I found a lot of ways to do this when you define the remove string in the program as a String literal: I can use ?i for example, but because remove is coming in as an argument and not a literal that I am defining in the program, this isn't working. Please check my attached picture so that you can see exactly where this is failing. Appreciate the help.

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {

      String array[] = base.split(remove);
      String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
          result+= array[i];

      return result;
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a reason you're using `split` and not `replaceAll` ?

Comment: FYI, you can do `String.join("", array)` instead of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.replaceAll() method accepts regex you can use directly like:

return base.replaceAll("(?i)(" + remove +")[\s]*", "")

Comment: thank you that's exactly what I needed. The issue was the way I was writing the code after split. I wrote it as base.split((?i)(remove));. it should have looked like ("(?i)("+remove+")")

Comment: This will fail on any special characters, like `.`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex pattern with `CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `LITERAL` flags:

```
return Pattern.compile(remove, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.LITERAL)
        .matcher(base).replaceAll("");
```

Comment: Which could also be done using `return base.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(remove), "");`